# How to pass a value of form field filled using jquery autocomplete selection to a new page

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery Autocomplete. It all works well. All i need help with is that when it fills aid in one of the text fields on selection of particular name i want it to send that aid to profile.php?aid= so that if someone selects persons name, that person can view his/her profile. 
profile.php is using $_GET['aid'] to get url parameter.

Code for your reference:

```
 <script>

$(function() {
    function log( message ) {
        $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
        $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#frndsrch" ).autocomplete({
        source: "searchfrnds.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
             $( "#project-icon" ).attr( "src", "" + ui.item.icon );
             $( "#project-desc" ).val( "Name:" + ui.item.value + " " + ui.item.lvalue+" & "+"About:"+ui.item.abt+" & "+ "Email ID:" + ui.item.email); 
             $( "#aid" ).val( ui.item.aid );


                 }
    });


});
</script>
```

Here aid goes into a text field with id="aid" on selection of name.

```
 <div class="ui-widget">
  <h1>Enter your friend's name</h1>
   <p>
  <label for="frndsrch"></label>
   <img src="images/transparent_1x1.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" class="ui-state-default" id="project-icon" />

      Enter Name:
   <input id="frndsrch" name="srch">
   <br />
    </p>

   <p>Further Information</p>
   <p> <textarea name="info" cols="50" rows="10" disabled="disabled" readonly="readonly" id="project-desc">As soon as you select a name from above, further information will be displayed here. 
   </textarea></p>
  <input type="text" name"aid" id="aid"/>
   </div>
```

Now how and where do i add

```
    <a href="profile.php?aid=<?php echo $_GET['aid']; ?>View Profile</a>
```

so that value from text field aid is passed to $aid.

Answer (score 0):

First create form with action PHP_SELF (so when you submit the form, it reloads the page) and add a submit button with the name='submit' to post the form and work with it later on in PHP.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="GET">
<div class="ui-widget">
    <h1>Enter your friend's name</h1>
    <p>
    <label for="frndsrch"></label>
    <img src="images/transparent_1x1.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" class="ui-state-default" id="project-icon" />

    Enter Name:
    <input id="frndsrch" name="srch">
    <br />
    </p>

    <p>Further Information</p>
    <p> <textarea name="info" cols="50" rows="10" disabled="disabled" readonly="readonly" id="project-desc">As soon as you select a name from above, further information will be displayed here. 
    </textarea></p>
    <input type="text" name"aid" id="aid"/>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"/>
```

Now create the PHP code to GET the aid value and echo it in the ANCHOR tag url attribute:

```
<?php
if (isset$_GET['submit']) {
     $aid = $_GET['aid'];
     echo "<a href='profile.php?aid=$aid'>View Profile</a>";

}
?>
```

Comment: Well i was experimenting a bit as i am new to jquery and found this solution. I added 

       $('a').attr('href',"profile.php?aid=" + ui.item.aid ); 

So now as soon as i click on the name it sends me to the profile page of that user. It worked well. Thanks anyway for the help. :)